# can't turn off auto tab control for visual studio 2017 text editor for basic

Tags: visual-studio

All of a sudden, starting today, VS text editor for VB keeps auto formatting tab insertions.  I'll hit enter at the end of a line of a complex if/else/end if structure, and entire structure shifts left, fouling up the formatting of my code.

I even tried Tools > Options > all languages > 
Indenting = None

..and it still does it.
Tried closing and opening Vs.

UPDATE:
The indenting problem is now at a completely different computer I work on, as if Visual Studio now propagates Tools > Options settings to EVERY computer I have VS installed on.

I tried Tools > import export > 
I've set Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Lang.. > Tabs > Indenting to NONE
and auto-indent still happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off:
Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic > Advanced > Editor Help > [ ] Pretty listing

(VS unexpectedly must have turned this feature on.  This is not the first time in my 20 years of using VS that it has self-modified its settings.)